# Ubuntu 16.04.2 - Connection reset by peer when ssh right after reboot

Tags: 16.04, ssh

I was able to ssh to a Ubuntu 16.04.2 server before reboot. So after reboot I tried to ssh, but failed with message `ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer`.

Weird part is that, after wait for 10 minutes or so, I am able to ssh to the server. Is there a time lock? If so how to reset that?

---

Below are my configs on the server:

- `sshd: ALL` in /etc/hosts.allow
- empty in /etc/hosts.deny
- firewall is inactive `ufw status   Status: inactive`
- ssh to server as `root` using public key
- enabled the following in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

  > PermitRootLogin without-password
  >
  > PubkeyAuthentication yes
  >
  > StrictModes no
  >
  > PasswordAuthentication yes
- In /root/.ssh/config I have the following:

  > Host *
  >
  > StrictHostKeyChecking no
- client's pub key is in server `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`

---

A detail log is here:

`ssh -vvv root@192.168.0.100
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /root/.ssh/config
debug1: /root/.ssh/config line 6: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "192.168.0.100" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.0.100 [192.168.0.100] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer`

Thank you!

Comment: "Connection reset by peer" is very hard to debug, as anything along the chain between you and the server could 'disconnect' the network connection for whatever reason.  It's entirely possible that your computer has to be properly on the network before it lets you out, and disconnects you until you've been on for a given period of time, but we can't possibly know whether that's the case just from this.  There's no default block, though, that would prevent you from using SSH.

Comment: I would run `systemd-analyze` on the server and see how long the boot time is.   Then if you run it with `systemd-analyze blame` you can hopefully see maybe something that it causing it to boot slowly.  Normally you should be able to ssh to a host once it is up.

Comment: Thanks! I finally get it resolved by reinstall the OS. Sadly I would never know the reason.

Comment: Please check the fail2ban service, which is designed for protection

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved the problem is I went to the host machine and ran a few commands.

```
sudo mkdir /var/run/sshd
sudo chmod 755 -R /var/run/sshd
sudo service ssh restart
```

I got connected to the machine after that.